# Segfault in libc upon running statically linked application

Tags: ubuntu, segmentation-fault, arm, libc, tegra

I am trying to run a statically linked hello world program on an ubuntu tegra (ARM) board, but a function within libc seems to be giving a segmentation fault.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00039a1a in _dl_get_origin ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00039a1a in _dl_get_origin ()
#1  0x0001abaa in _dl_non_dynamic_init ()
#2  0x0001b5d8 in __libc_init_first ()
#3  0x00008ae2 in __libc_start_main ()
#4  0x000088d4 in _start ()
```

When dynamically linked, there are no problems whatsoever.

Some more details:

```
a.out: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=f56e8ee17aa966e641c8b4e1ba3105abc077a143, not stripped

gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2

Linux tegra-ubuntu 3.10.24-g6a2d13a #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Apr 18 15:56:45 PDT 2014 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Any pointers on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Is this cross-compiled or built natively? Differences between a cross-compiler's libc and the one on the target would be an obvious culprit, but that that version implies a native GCC package. Either way, there's not really enough information here to actually debug it. Where in the function does the fault happen ([it seems pretty straightforward](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/dl-origin.c;hb=HEAD))? What's the actual bad address (at worst it should be possible to figure it out from the disassembly and the register state at the time)?

Comment: Everything is native on the ARM board. I wish I could dig deeper but that would mean compiling libc from source so that gdb gets me access into internal state.